# Bootstrap tabs and delegation example

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of items in a left column, that when I click on one, will refresh the content of the right column. This works great.

Problem is, I have bootstrap tabs loading in the content on the right.  When they come in after the DOM is loaded, I no longer have access to the 'show' event.  My code works great when the tabs are loaded at the same time as the rest of the dom, but when loaded after, I am guessing the events aren't available since these were added after it was done loading.

I've been pouring over these forums and the rest of the net for an idea on how to fix this, and I'm sure one of you rockstars has come acrossed this and provided a solution.

For the sake of illustration, here is some sample code that I am trying to get working:

```
<ul id="tabMenu" style="background: #D1D2D4;" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#t-5">Content</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#t-9">Project</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#t-6">SEO</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#t-7">Image</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#t-10">Workflow</a></li>
</ul>


$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show', function (e) {
     console.log(e.target); // activated tab
});
```

When I run this when the tabs are loaded with the page, it works great.  But, when I run it and these are loaded after (like the .load event I mentioned), the show event doesn't seem to fire.

Can someone tell me either:
a.) If I am doing something wrong, and what I can do to fix it

b.) Let me know if delegate (or some other method) would fix this, and provide an example syntax I could try?

I greatly appreciate any help the community can provide.

Comment: Also - for the sake of reference, assume that jQuery 1.9.1 is loaded and working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
$(function(){
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show', function (e) {
         console.log(e.target); // activated tab
    });
})
```

But if your doing with dynamic content. try it:

```
function bindtabs(){
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show', function (e) {
         console.log(e.target); // activated tab
    });
}
```

And after you create your tabs you call it:

```
//creating tabs code here
bindtabs();
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, but this didn't make any difference in my code.  The version that loaded with the dom worked great, and I saw the message in the console.  The tabs that were loaded after didn't show the message.

Comment: Ok, try to use the "bindtabs()" every time you load a new tab after DOM. It'll solve

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer, sorry, didn't know you were still updating it.  I tried your second and third blocks, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Show the code are you creating tabs and i can say what's going wrong.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. You already have the code for the tabs, not sure what you are looking for, can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the deferred syntax of `on` instead:

```
$(document).on('show', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]' function (e) {
     console.log(e.target); // activated tab
});
```

It should fire on elements that are added later.

Comment: Sorry, no dice.  Works great on the version where they are already loaded, doesn't work on tabs loaded in a div after the dom has finished (using .load to pull on the contents of a file).

Comment: At this point I think a JSFiddle is the best course of action if you can.

Comment: I fixed the error.  It had to do with a duplicate reference to a plugin that caused the tabs to stop working.  Appreciate the help and the suggestions.